# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.graphics.dvd')

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Im playing around with react-native and fetching some data from a API. All good. When im trying to display the data into my  then I can only display the first like data.artistName, but when im trying to access data.graphics.dvd I get the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.graphics.dvd')"

The graphics is a object.

```
const Videos = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
     fetch('https://myurl.com/api/title/5fac58f764e6710/')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }
    fetchPost();
    
  }, []);

    return (
  
 
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
     
    <Text style={styles.title}>{data.artistName}{data.graphics.dvd}</Text>
      
    </View>
   )
  };
```

Comment: If you get that errors it's because graphics is null and you are trying to get "dvd" of null. Have you checked that data contains "graphics" ?

Comment: Yes, the thing is that if the app reloads and stays on that screen, I get the data. But when navigate to that page, I do not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial state, you define `data` as an empty array:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

That means that on first render, `data == []`
At that point, when you access `data.artistName`, that evaluates to `undefined`, but doesn't cause a type error.

However, when `data === []`, and then you try to get `data.graphics.dvd`, you get a type error because `graphics` is undefined and you're trying to get `dvd` from it.

To solve this, do a check for `data` actually contains something something before you render that section:

```
{(data.artistName && data.graphics) ? <Text style={styles.title}>{data.artistName}{data.graphics.dvd}</Text> : null}
```

Another way to deal with this (before you're in the body of the return statement) would be to check `data` and do a different return if nothing is there yet:

```
if (loading) {
  return <Text>Loading...</Text>
}

return (<View/>) //your normal return
```

This is all predicated on `data.graphics` existing once your API call returns, which a commenter on the original post mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I'm understand! It has not been able to load all the data så it returns undefined. Am I right? Works like a charm with your solution! Thank you.

Comment: The timeline will go something like this: 1) Initial render 2) `useEffect` runs 3) `fetch` inside `useEffect` returns 4) Next render.  So, until step 4, you don't have any data yet.